Как создать наилучшую систему с характеристиками героев C#
Есть вот такой скрипт:
    public class data_character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class barbarian
    {
        public static string rare = "common";
        public static int baby_amount = 0;
        public static int classic_amount = 0;
        public static int super_amount = 0;
    }...
}

Дальше после "..." еще несколько классов. Вопрос такой: как из другого скрипта например создать массив (ну или лист) всех классов у которых например rare == "epic"
Если в данном коде это не реализуемо, порекомендуйте пожалуйста другие варианты решения. Заранее спасибо!

Для начала, стоит забыть про существование static, начать писать названия классов с большой буквы (видите, как MonoBehavior написан? вот так же), почитать что-то про ООП, а конкретно наследование и узнать, для чего в Unity нужен ScriptableObject. И только потом можно будет приступать к решению вашего вопроса, а именно сделать общего наследника, добавить все экземпляры в коллекцию и и уже в ней фильтровать, например с помощью Linq. А вообще все такие штуки должны быть в метаданных игры, а не в хардкоде, но это уже потом.

Если конкретной помощи ждёте, показывайте весь паровоз классов, так как пока непонятно, что у них общего, а что разного, а это важно для ответа. Вопрос можете отредактировать.

@Tlysed, static это ужасно, потому, что порочный вид связи, которым легко воспользоваться, которым может пользоваться, даже тот кто вааще не умеет создавать связи. А кончается всё, максимально плохо, и для проекта, который стал как свалка, которую не возможно поддерживать, и для программиста, который ничему не научился и сидит на static, как на игле.

Ну в лоб, так в лоб.
Берём класс
public class CharacterData
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly string Rare;
    public int BabyAmount;
    public int ClassicAmount;
    public int SuperAmount;

    public CharacterData(string name, string rare)
    {
        Name = name;
        Rare = rare;
    }  
}

Берём класс, который будет всё это заполнять, и раз уж вам так нравится, пусть будет статическим (но я предупреждал).
public static class CharacterDataManager
{
    public static readonly CharacterData[] Values = CreateData().ToArray();

    private static IEnumerable<CharacterData> CreateData()
    {
        yield return new CharacterData("barbarian", "common");
        yield return new CharacterData("mage", "epic");
        // и так далее добавляйте строки
    }
}

Теперь ответ на вопрос, как получить rare == "epic"
using System.Linq;

CharacterData[] epics = CharacterDataManager.Values.Where(x => x.Rare == "epic").ToArray();

Ну или циклом
foreach (CharacterData epic in CharacterDataManager.Values.Where(x => x.Rare == "epic"))
{
    Debug.Log(epic.Name);
}

Ну или вообще без Linq, если так понятнее
foreach (CharacterData epic in CharacterDataManager.Values)
{
    if (epic.Rare == "epic")
    {
        Debug.Log(epic.Name);
    }
}

Как взять объект по имени, если требуется
CharacterData barbarian = CharacterDataManager.Values.First(x => x.Name == "barbarian");
barbarian.BabyAmount++;


static... ты бы ему ещё показал как пить и курить...

@Yaroslav так он умеет уже. Ответ так себе, согласен, но автору до вменяемых структур данных ещё учиться и учиться.

Никогда не лишний раз напомнить о том что написано на этикетке, о вреде употребления  Иначе можно жить и не знать  Пока не наткнёшься на хейт static пару раз, многие и не задумаются, может с этим действительно что-то не так...

Понимаю, что мой вопрос тупой, я уже скажем с нуля, под руководством Unity, создал все через Scriptable Objects, создал систему загрузки и отгрузки на сервера через Json. Кстати такой вопрос, стоит ли смотреть курс Сакутина на ютубе, по C# и Unity и какие уроки/книги порекомендуете?

@Tlysed я не шарю в Unity, я так, игрался с ней пару раз для спортивного интереса, вон Yaroslav шарит. Но сам .NET и C# хорошо знаю. Я бы на вашем месте поизучал, а что за зверь такой C# в отрыве от Unity. Поизучал бы ООП, узнал бы, почему так странно разные люди про static отзываются и т. д. А потом уже вернулся бы к играм.
